# how can I print the summary of the RobertaForMaskedLM model in pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model

I am trying to get the summary of the RobertaForMaskedLM model with the following code:

```
from transformers import RobertaForMaskedLM
from torchsummary import summary
from transformers import RobertaConfig
config = RobertaConfig(
    vocab_size=20_000,  # we align this to the tokenizer vocab_size
    max_position_embeddings=512,
    hidden_size=768,
    num_attention_heads=12,
    num_hidden_layers=6,
    type_vocab_size=1)


model = RobertaForMaskedLM(config)

summary(model,(16,512))
```

I get the following error when executing the code:

File "C:\Users\Consorcio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\transformers\models\roberta\modeling_roberta.py", line 806, in forward
batch_size, seq_length = input_shape
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

the input to the model I understand is the batch size=16, and the length of the input sequence=512
what am I doing wrong?